# How to find duplicate key in mongo DB collection?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have the below data where there are 2 `BookNumber` fields. I would like to get the number of such duplicate `BookNumber` fields in my collection. Please let us know on this.

[image]

```json
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63f783fa63065dcb9566e1ec"),
    "BookNumber" : "NOO1034687",
    "BookNumber" : "NOO1034680",
    "programCode" : "CSE"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63f783fa63065dcb9566e1ed"),
    "BookNumber" : "NOO1034685",
    "programCode" : "IT"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63f783fa63065dcb9566e1ee"),
    "BookNumber" : "NOO1034686",
    "programCode" : "Mech"
}
```

I have tried to get the Duplicate key from that collection, but that didn't worked.

Comment: Are they real data? Not sure if it is possible to duplicate fields with same name in MongoDB

Comment: @ray I have attached the image for reference "enter image description here". I have added the same filed name from robo Mongo, it got added. Using Mongo DB version 4.4

Comment: Can you share the code about how you insert the data? It is interesting that we cannot replicate the duplicate fields.

Comment: Using robo 3T, just edited that record then added duplicate fields.

Comment: Can you try with another DB client other than robo 3T to confirm whether the issue still persists? Robo 3T is [deprecated](https://robomongo.org/) a while ago and may have some unexpected bug due to lack of maintenance. You may want to check whether the record is really persisted in the database or the duplicate fields is just a display of UI / DB client

Answer (score 0):

As @ray stated, you cannot have two fields with the same name in one document in mongo. If you try to do that, the values of the fields will be overridden and you will end up with one field.

Comment: I have attached the image for reference "enter image description here". I have added the same filed name from robo  Mongo, it got added. Using Mongo DB version 4.4